# My media query doesn't seem to be affecting the style

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor, blazor-server-side

Given:
Bootstrap 5.1
VS 2022 Pro

My media query doesn't seem to be working when I rotate the screen.

[image]

razor page

```
@page "/"

<div class="d-flex flex-row bg-secondary">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">
        <div class="txl">Widget 1</div>
        <div class="txn">55</div>
        <div class="txl">Widget 2</div>
        <div class="txn">55</div>
        <div class="txl">Widget 3</div>
        <div class="txn">55</div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-warning">
        <div class="nsl">Widget ID</div>
        <div class="nsn">55</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css page

```
html {
}

@media (max-width: 845px){
    html {
        font-size: 2px;        
    }
}

.txl {
    font-size: 4.75rem;
    
}

.txn {
    font-size: 10rem;
}

.nsl {
    font-size: 7rem;
}

.nsn {
    font-size: 35rem;
    line-height: 30rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
}
```

Comment: Your code performs perfectly on a sample Blazor app. In responsive mode (390 x 844, vertically oriented), the font does fit the screen. I would recommend checking the container, as you have newly mentioned a container issue in a different thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77277449/how-can-i-make-the-main-container-take-up-entire-screen

Answer (score 0):

In your css Try changing from html to *

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).