# How can I make the main container take up entire screen?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, blazor, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side

Given:
Bootstrap 5.1
VS 2022 Pro
Blazor Server App

How can I make the container take up entire screen no margins all around?

```
<div class="container bg-primary">
  Hello World!
</div>
```

This is what that currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: This is easy to answer in terms of CSS. But having to consider Bootscrap … meh, that's really a problem you don't need to have. Maybe read the docs.

Comment: According to [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/containers/) (and also by common convention), `.container` class is always assigned a set `max-width` value. If you want it to be full viewport width, you might need to adjust the HTML markup and probably ditch the `container` class. In any case, it might be answered with a fuller HTML context.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for the "container-fluid" class instead of "container".

Try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-primary">
Hello World!
</div>
```

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/

Answer (score 0):

Modify the last section of mainLayout.razor.css to：

```
@media (min-width: 641px) {
    .page {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
        height: 100vh;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
    }

    .top-row {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        padding-left: 2rem !important;
        padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
    }

    article {
       height:100vh;

    }

}
```

MainLayout.razor:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content ps-0 pt-0">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```

In your target component:

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-primary" style="height:100vh">
    Hello World!
</div>
```

Result:

[image]